# Where can I ask if a news article is true, if the topics include electronics and biology?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I would like to know if I can use Stack Exchange for asking about finding the truth of a news article like this:

[Iran unveils ‘smart system’ to detect virus from 100m in seconds, faces derision](https://www.timesofisrael.com/iran-unveils-smart-system-to-detect-virus-possibly-based-on-fake-bomb-sensor/)

It is related to some fields of science including electronics (magnetic fields) and biology and papers like [this](https://scholar.google.com.ua/scholar?q=virus%20detection%20by%20magnetic%20field&hl=fa&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart):

[image: Screenshot of Google results for virus detection by magnetic fields]

I would like to save time and use the SE network to research it, instead of reading those papers and finding some viewpoint about this news and the reality of it.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but are you skeptical of the claims of Iran's government and you want to ask if it is true or not? It **might** be on-topic at https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/. You should check the help page to make sure though.

Comment: That claim is simply bullshit, the explanation is just gibberish and doesn't mean anything. The question would generally be on-topic on Skeptics if you formulate it well, the most important part is quoting a notable claim, which you could do from this article. It's also a kind of question that is a bit annoying on Skeptics because answers are required to cite sources, which is a bit harder for entirely fantastical claims such as this one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To quote [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com)' [What topic can I ask about here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page (emphasis my own):

> Skeptics Stack Exchange is for challenging unreferenced notable claims, pseudoscience and biased results.
>
> Skeptics is about applying skepticism — it is for researching the evidence behind claims you encounter. It is not for speculation, philosophical discussions or investigating original claims.
>
> New users (even users familiar with the Stack Exchange format) should read our introduction to the site before posting.
>
> **If you have a question about the accuracy of public claims made in the media or elsewhere, if you're interested in the evidence behind what you hear or read, then you are in the right place.**

So, it seems like [Skeptics SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com) would be the right place for such a question.

Comment: Thanks @Mureinik, i asked [here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/47379/about-iran-unveils-smart-system-to-detect-virus-from-100m-in-seconds)

Comment: @sosa Uh oh, looks like your question was deleted. So it turns out that this isn't the correct site.

Comment: @mindstormsboi topicality isn't the only problem that leads to post closure or deletion.